# How to change selection area for path in SVG using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg-edit

I am working in SVG editor 2.7 version. Here I need to change selection area for path tags in SVG using Javascript.

For example refer this image below:

[image: Path selection image]

Here I analysis about SVG editor, `<g>` tags will generated automatically and create only one selection area which is provided only rectangular shape only.
Here I need to change selection area for path section.

Below code is based on `select.js` :

```
(function() {'use strict';

if (!svgedit.select) {
    svgedit.select = {};
}

var svgFactory_;
var config_;
var selectorManager_; // A Singleton
var gripRadius = svgedit.browser.isTouch() ? 5 : 4;
// Class: svgedit.select.Selector
// Private class for DOM element selection boxes
//
// Parameters:
// id - integer to internally indentify the selector
// elem - DOM element associated with this selector
svgedit.select.Selector = function(id, elem) {
    // this is the selector's unique number
    this.id = id;

    // this holds a reference to the element for which this selector is being used
    this.selectedElement = elem;

    // this is a flag used internally to track whether the selector is being used or not
    this.locked = true;

    // this holds a reference to the <g> element that holds all visual elements of the selector
    this.selectorGroup = svgFactory_.createSVGElement({
        'element': 'g',
        'attr': {'id': ('selectorGroup' + this.id)}
    });

    // this holds a reference to the path rect
    this.selectorRect = this.selectorGroup.appendChild(
        svgFactory_.createSVGElement({
            'element': 'path',
            'attr': {
                'id': ('selectedBox' + this.id),
                'fill': 'none',
                'stroke': '#22C',
                'stroke-width': '1',
                'stroke-dasharray': '5,5',
                // need to specify this so that the rect is not selectable
                'style': 'pointer-events:none'
            }
        })
    );

    // this holds a reference to the grip coordinates for this selector
    this.gripCoords = {
        'nw': null,
        'n' : null,
        'ne': null,
        'e' : null,
        'se': null,
        's' : null,
        'sw': null,
        'w' : null
    };

    this.reset(this.selectedElement);
};


// Function: svgedit.select.Selector.reset
// Used to reset the id and element that the selector is attached to
//
// Parameters:
// e - DOM element associated with this selector
svgedit.select.Selector.prototype.reset = function(e) {
    this.locked = true;
    this.selectedElement = e;
    this.resize();
    this.selectorGroup.setAttribute('display', 'inline');
};

// Function: svgedit.select.Selector.updateGripCursors
// Updates cursors for corner grips on rotation so arrows point the right way
//
// Parameters:
// angle - Float indicating current rotation angle in degrees
svgedit.select.Selector.prototype.updateGripCursors = function(angle) {
    var dir,
        dir_arr = [],
        steps = Math.round(angle / 45);
    if (steps < 0) {steps += 8;}
    for (dir in selectorManager_.selectorGrips) {
        dir_arr.push(dir);
    }
    while (steps > 0) {
        dir_arr.push(dir_arr.shift());
        steps--;
    }
    var i = 0;
    for (dir in selectorManager_.selectorGrips) {
        selectorManager_.selectorGrips[dir].setAttribute('style', ('cursor:' + dir_arr[i] + '-resize'));
        i++;
    }
};

// Function: svgedit.select.Selector.showGrips
// Show the resize grips of this selector
//
// Parameters:
// show - boolean indicating whether grips should be shown or not
svgedit.select.Selector.prototype.showGrips = function(show) {
    // TODO: use suspendRedraw() here
    var bShow = show ? 'inline' : 'none';
    selectorManager_.selectorGripsGroup.setAttribute('display', bShow);
    var elem = this.selectedElement;
    this.hasGrips = show;
    if (elem && show) {
        this.selectorGroup.appendChild(selectorManager_.selectorGripsGroup);
        this.updateGripCursors(svgedit.utilities.getRotationAngle(elem));
    }
};

// Function: svgedit.select.Selector.resize
// Updates the selector to match the element's size
svgedit.select.Selector.prototype.resize = function() {
console.log(this.selectorGroup);
    var selectedBox = this.selectorRect,
     selectorRubberBand = this.getRubberBandBox,
        mgr = selectorManager_,
        selectedGrips = mgr.selectorGrips,
        selected = this.selectedElement,
        sw = selected.getAttribute('stroke-width'),
        current_zoom = svgFactory_.currentZoom();
        $('#current_zoom').val(current_zoom);
        console.log(mgr);
    var offset = 1/current_zoom;
    if (selected.getAttribute('stroke') !== 'none' && !isNaN(sw)) {
        offset += (sw/2);
    }

    var tagName = selected.tagName;
    if (tagName === 'text') {
        offset += 2/current_zoom;
    }

    // loop and transform our bounding box until we reach our first rotation
    var tlist = svgedit.transformlist.getTransformList(selected);
    var m = svgedit.math.transformListToTransform(tlist).matrix;

    // This should probably be handled somewhere else, but for now
    // it keeps the selection box correctly positioned when zoomed
    m.e *= current_zoom;
    m.f *= current_zoom;

    var bbox = svgedit.utilities.getBBox(selected);
    if (tagName === 'g' && !$.data(selected, 'gsvg')) {
        // The bbox for a group does not include stroke vals, so we
        // get the bbox based on its children.
        var stroked_bbox = svgFactory_.getStrokedBBox(selected.childNodes);
        if (stroked_bbox) {
            bbox = stroked_bbox;
        }
    }

    // apply the transforms
    var l = bbox.x, t = bbox.y, w = bbox.width, h = bbox.height;
    bbox = {x:l, y:t, width:w, height:h};



          var x_varadd=70;  
          var y_varadd=40;                
          var cen_x=l;    
          var cen_y=t;    

          var dummyvarrr=0; 

          var gethide_curtselid=$("#hide_curtselid").val();
         var gethide_curtselwidth=$("#hide_curtdrawx_width").val(w);
        var gethide_curtselheight=$("#hide_curtdrawy_height").val(h);  


          $("#hide_curtdrawx_id").val(l);  
          $("#hide_curtdrawy_id").val(t); 

          var gethide_curtselid12=$("#hide_curtdrawx_id").val();    
          var gethide_curtselid13=$("#hide_curtdrawy_id").val();  


    offset *= current_zoom;

    var nbox = svgedit.math.transformBox(l*current_zoom, t*current_zoom, w*current_zoom, h*current_zoom, m),
        aabox = nbox.aabox,
        nbax = aabox.x - offset,
        nbay = aabox.y - offset,
        nbaw = aabox.width + (offset * 2),
        nbah = aabox.height + (offset * 2);
        var gethide_curtselwidth=$("#hide_curtdrawx_width").val(nbaw);
            var gethide_curtselheight=$("#hide_curtdrawy_height").val(nbah);  
            $("#hide_curtdrawx_id").val(nbax);  
            $("#hide_curtdrawy_id").val(nbay);

    // now if the shape is rotated, un-rotate it
    var cx = nbax + nbaw/2,
        cy = nbay + nbah/2;

    var angle = svgedit.utilities.getRotationAngle(selected);
    if (angle) {
        var rot = svgFactory_.svgRoot().createSVGTransform();
        rot.setRotate(-angle, cx, cy);
        var rotm = rot.matrix;
        nbox.tl = svgedit.math.transformPoint(nbox.tl.x, nbox.tl.y, rotm);
        nbox.tr = svgedit.math.transformPoint(nbox.tr.x, nbox.tr.y, rotm);
        nbox.bl = svgedit.math.transformPoint(nbox.bl.x, nbox.bl.y, rotm);
        nbox.br = svgedit.math.transformPoint(nbox.br.x, nbox.br.y, rotm);

        // calculate the axis-aligned bbox
        var tl = nbox.tl;
        var minx = tl.x,
            miny = tl.y,
            maxx = tl.x,
            maxy = tl.y;

        var min = Math.min, max = Math.max;

        minx = min(minx, min(nbox.tr.x, min(nbox.bl.x, nbox.br.x) ) ) - offset;
        miny = min(miny, min(nbox.tr.y, min(nbox.bl.y, nbox.br.y) ) ) - offset;
        maxx = max(maxx, max(nbox.tr.x, max(nbox.bl.x, nbox.br.x) ) ) + offset;
        maxy = max(maxy, max(nbox.tr.y, max(nbox.bl.y, nbox.br.y) ) ) + offset;

        nbax = minx;
        nbay = miny;
        nbaw = (maxx-minx);
        nbah = (maxy-miny);
    }
    var sr_handle = svgFactory_.svgRoot().suspendRedraw(100);

    var dstr = 'M' + nbax + ',' + nbay
                + ' L' + (nbax+nbaw) + ',' + nbay
                + ' ' + (nbax+nbaw) + ',' + (nbay+nbah)
                + ' ' + nbax + ',' + (nbay+nbah) + 'z';
                // alert(dstr);
    selectedBox.setAttribute('d', dstr);

    var xform = angle ? 'rotate(' + [angle, cx, cy].join(',') + ')' : '';
    this.selectorGroup.setAttribute('transform', xform);

    // TODO(codedread): Is this if needed?
//  if (selected === selectedElements[0]) {
        this.gripCoords = {
            'nw': [nbax, nbay],
            'ne': [nbax+nbaw, nbay],
            'sw': [nbax, nbay+nbah],
            'se': [nbax+nbaw, nbay+nbah],
            'n':  [nbax + (nbaw)/2, nbay],
            'w':    [nbax, nbay + (nbah)/2],
            'e':    [nbax + nbaw, nbay + (nbah)/2],
            's':    [nbax + (nbaw)/2, nbay + nbah]
        };

            var width_rect = nbaw-offset;
        var height_rect = nbah-offset;
        var conversation =$('#measurement_det').val();
    // alert(conversation);
    if(conversation =='Meter') {
        var width_gets = (parseFloat(width_rect)/100).toFixed(2)+'m';
        var height_gets = (parseFloat(height_rect)/100).toFixed(2)+'m';
    }
    if(conversation =='Feet') {
        var width_gets = (parseFloat(width_rect)/100)*3.2808399;
        var feet_w = Math.floor(width_gets);
        var inches_w = Math.round((width_gets - feet_w) * 12);
        var width_gets = feet_w + "'" + inches_w + '"';
        var width_gets = width_gets+'ft';
        var height_gets = (parseFloat(height_rect)/100)*3.2808399;
        var feet_h = Math.floor(height_gets);
        var inches_h = Math.round((height_gets - feet_h) * 12);
        var height_gets = feet_h + "'" + inches_h + '"';
        var height_gets = height_gets+'ft';
        }
        if(selected.tagName=='rect')
        {

        var rect_text_id=selected.parentNode.id; 
        var rect_text_id1=rect_text_id.split('_');
        }
        if(selected.tagName=='g')
        {
        var sslice = selected.childNodes;
            if(sslice[0].tagName=='rect')
            {
            var rect_text_id=sslice[0].parentNode.id;
            var rect_text_id1=rect_text_id.split('_');
            }
        }

        var dir;
        for (dir in this.gripCoords) {
            var coords = this.gripCoords[dir];
            if((dir =='n') || (dir =='e') || (dir =='s') || (dir =='w')) {
            /* selectedGrips[dir].setAttribute('cx', coords[0]);  
            selectedGrips[dir].setAttribute('cy', coords[1]); */
            /* $('#selectorGrip_resize_n').html('');
            $('#selectorGrip_resize_s').html(''); */
            if(selected.childNodes[0] && selected.childNodes[0].tagName=='rect')
                {
                $('#meter_range_rect'+rect_text_id1[3]+'_n').text(width_gets);
                $('#meter_range_rect'+rect_text_id1[3]+'_n').attr({'font-weight':''});
                $('#meter_range_rect'+rect_text_id1[3]+'_s').text(width_gets);
                $('#meter_range_rect'+rect_text_id1[3]+'_s').attr({'font-weight':''});
                }   


            if(dir =='w') { 
            selectedGrips[dir].setAttribute('transform', 'rotate(-90,'+coords[0]+','+coords[1]+')');
            // $('#selectorGrip_resize_w').html(''); 
            if(selected.childNodes[0] && selected.childNodes[0].tagName=='rect')
            {
                $('#meter_range_rect'+rect_text_id1[3]+'_w').text(height_gets);
                $('#meter_range_rect'+rect_text_id1[3]+'_w').attr({'font-weight':''});
            }
            }
            if(dir =='e') {
            selectedGrips[dir].setAttribute('transform', 'rotate(-90,'+coords[0]+','+coords[1]+')');
            // $('#selectorGrip_resize_e').html('');
            if(selected.childNodes[0] && selected.childNodes[0].tagName=='rect')
            {
                $('#meter_range_rect'+rect_text_id1[3]+'_e').text(height_gets);
                $('#meter_range_rect'+rect_text_id1[3]+'_e').attr({'font-weight':''});
            }
            }
            selectedGrips[dir].setAttribute('cx', coords[0]);  
            selectedGrips[dir].setAttribute('cy', coords[1]);

            }
             else {
                selectedGrips[dir].setAttribute('cx', coords[0]);  
                selectedGrips[dir].setAttribute('cy', coords[1]); 
            }
        }

        // we want to go 20 pixels in the negative transformed y direction, ignoring scale
        mgr.rotateGripConnector.setAttribute('x1', nbax + (nbaw)/2);
        mgr.rotateGripConnector.setAttribute('y1', nbay);
        mgr.rotateGripConnector.setAttribute('x2', nbax + (nbaw)/2);
        mgr.rotateGripConnector.setAttribute('y2', nbay - (gripRadius*5));

        mgr.rotateGrip.setAttribute('cx', nbax + (nbaw)/2);
        mgr.rotateGrip.setAttribute('cy', nbay - (gripRadius*5));
//  }

    svgFactory_.svgRoot().unsuspendRedraw(sr_handle);
};


// Class: svgedit.select.SelectorManager
svgedit.select.SelectorManager = function() {
    // this will hold the <g> element that contains all selector rects/grips
    this.selectorParentGroup = null;

    // this is a special rect that is used for multi-select
    this.rubberBandBox = null;

    // this will hold objects of type svgedit.select.Selector (see above)
    this.selectors = [];

    // this holds a map of SVG elements to their Selector object
    this.selectorMap = {};

    // this holds a reference to the grip elements
    this.selectorGrips = {
        'nw': null,
        'n' :  null,
        'ne': null,
        'e' :  null,
        'se': null,
        's' :  null,
        'sw': null,
        'w' :  null
    };

    this.selectorGripsGroup = null;
    this.rotateGripConnector = null;
    this.rotateGrip = null;

    this.initGroup();
};

// Function: svgedit.select.SelectorManager.initGroup
// Resets the parent selector group element
svgedit.select.SelectorManager.prototype.initGroup = function() {
    // remove old selector parent group if it existed
    if (this.selectorParentGroup && this.selectorParentGroup.parentNode) {
        this.selectorParentGroup.parentNode.removeChild(this.selectorParentGroup);
    }

    // create parent selector group and add it to svgroot
    this.selectorParentGroup = svgFactory_.createSVGElement({
        'element': 'g',
        'attr': {'id': 'selectorParentGroup'}
    });
    this.selectorGripsGroup = svgFactory_.createSVGElement({
        'element': 'g',
        'attr': {'display': 'none'}
    });
    this.selectorParentGroup.appendChild(this.selectorGripsGroup);
    svgFactory_.svgRoot().appendChild(this.selectorParentGroup);

    this.selectorMap = {};
    this.selectors = [];
    this.rubberBandBox = null;

    // add the corner grips
    var dir;
    for (dir in this.selectorGrips) {
        var grip = svgFactory_.createSVGElement({
            'element': 'circle',
            'attr': {
                'id': ('selectorGrip_resize_' + dir),
                'fill': '#04739E',
                'r': gripRadius,
                'style': ('cursor:' + dir + '-resize'),
                // This expands the mouse-able area of the grips making them
                // easier to grab with the mouse.
                // This works in Opera and WebKit, but does not work in Firefox
                // see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=500174
                'stroke-width': 2,
                'pointer-events': 'all'
            }
        });
    /*  if((dir =='n') || (dir =='e') || (dir =='s') || (dir =='w')) {

        var grip = svgFactory_.createSVGElement({ 
            'element': 'text',
            'attr': {

                'id': ('selectorGrip_resize_' + dir),
                'fill': '#3F7F00',
                // 'r': gripRadius,
                'style': ('cursor:' + dir + '-resize'),
                // This expands the mouse-able area of the grips making them
                // easier to grab with the mouse.
                // This works in Opera and WebKit, but does not work in Firefox
                // see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=500174
                'stroke-width': 2,
                'pointer-events': 'all'
            }
        });

        grip.textContent = ''; 


        }else {
            var grip = svgFactory_.createSVGElement({ 
            'element': 'circle',
            'attr': {
                'id': ('selectorGrip_resize_' + dir),
                'fill': '#04739E',
                'r': gripRadius,
                'style': ('cursor:' + dir + '-resize'),
                // This expands the mouse-able area of the grips making them
                // easier to grab with the mouse.
                // This works in Opera and WebKit, but does not work in Firefox
                // see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=500174
                'stroke-width': 2,
                'pointer-events': 'all'
            }
        }); 
        }
 */
        $.data(grip, 'dir', dir);
        $.data(grip, 'type', 'resize');
        this.selectorGrips[dir] = this.selectorGripsGroup.appendChild(grip);
    }

    // add rotator elems
    this.rotateGripConnector = this.selectorGripsGroup.appendChild(
        svgFactory_.createSVGElement({
            'element': 'line',
            'attr': {
                'id': ('selectorGrip_rotateconnector'),
                'stroke': '#22C',
                'stroke-width': '0'
            }
        })
    );

    this.rotateGrip = this.selectorGripsGroup.appendChild(
        svgFactory_.createSVGElement({
            'element': 'circle',
            'attr': {
                'id': 'selectorGrip_rotate',
                'fill': 'url(#rotate)',
                'r': '15',
                'stroke': '#22C',
                'stroke-width': 2,
                'style': "cursor:url(" + config_.imgPath + "rotate.png) 12 12, auto;"
            }
        })
    );
    $.data(this.rotateGrip, 'type', 'rotate');

    if ($('#canvasBackground').length) {return;}

    var dims = config_.dimensions;
    var canvasbg = svgFactory_.createSVGElement({
        'element': 'svg',
        'attr': {
            'id': 'canvasBackground',
            'width': dims[0],
            'height': dims[1],
            'x': 0,
            'y': 0,
            'overflow': (svgedit.browser.isWebkit() ? 'none' : 'visible'), // Chrome 7 has a problem with this when zooming out
            'style': 'pointer-events:none'
        }
    });

    var rect = svgFactory_.createSVGElement({
        'element': 'rect',
        'attr': {
            'width': '100%',
            'height': '100%',
            'x': 0,
            'y': 0,
            'stroke-width': 1,
            'stroke': '#000',
            'fill': '#FFF',
            'style': 'pointer-events:none'
        }
    });

    // Both Firefox and WebKit are too slow with this filter region (especially at higher
    // zoom levels) and Opera has at least one bug
//  if (!svgedit.browser.isOpera()) rect.setAttribute('filter', 'url(#canvashadow)');
    canvasbg.appendChild(rect);
    svgFactory_.svgRoot().insertBefore(canvasbg, svgFactory_.svgContent());
};

// Function: svgedit.select.SelectorManager.requestSelector
// Returns the selector based on the given element
//
// Parameters:
// elem - DOM element to get the selector for
svgedit.select.SelectorManager.prototype.requestSelector = function(elem) {
    if (elem == null) {return null;}
    var i,
        N = this.selectors.length;
    // If we've already acquired one for this element, return it.
    if (typeof(this.selectorMap[elem.id]) == 'object') {
        this.selectorMap[elem.id].locked = true;
        $("#hide_curtselid").val(elem.id); 
        return this.selectorMap[elem.id];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        if (this.selectors[i] && !this.selectors[i].locked) {
            this.selectors[i].locked = true;
            this.selectors[i].reset(elem);
            this.selectorMap[elem.id] = this.selectors[i];
            return this.selectors[i];
        }
    }
    // if we reached here, no available selectors were found, we create one
    this.selectors[N] = new svgedit.select.Selector(N, elem);
    this.selectorParentGroup.appendChild(this.selectors[N].selectorGroup);
    this.selectorMap[elem.id] = this.selectors[N];
    return this.selectors[N];
};

// Function: svgedit.select.SelectorManager.requestSelectors
// Returns the selector based on the given Rect and line and Path
//
// Parameters:
// elem - DOM element to get the selector for
svgedit.select.SelectorManager.prototype.requestSelectors = function(elem) {
    if (elem == null) {return null;}
    var i,
        N = this.selectors.length;

        // console.log(elem);
    // If we've already acquired one for this element, return it.
    if (typeof(this.selectorMap[elem.id]) == 'object') {
        this.selectorMap[elem.id].locked = true;
        $("#hide_curtselid").val(elem.id); 
        return this.selectorMap[elem.id];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        if (this.selectors[i] && !this.selectors[i].locked) {
            this.selectors[i].locked = true;
            this.selectors[i].reset(elem);
            this.selectorMap[elem.id] = this.selectors[i];
            return this.selectors[i];
        }
    }
    // if we reached here, no available selectors were found, we create one
    this.selectors[N] = new svgedit.select.Selector(N, elem);
    this.selectorParentGroup.appendChild(this.selectors[N].selectorGroup);
    this.selectorMap[elem.id] = this.selectors[N];
    return this.selectors[N];
};

// Function: svgedit.select.SelectorManager.releaseSelector
// Removes the selector of the given element (hides selection box)
//
// Parameters:
// elem - DOM element to remove the selector for
svgedit.select.SelectorManager.prototype.releaseSelector = function(elem) {
    if (elem == null) {return;}
    var i,
        N = this.selectors.length,
        sel = this.selectorMap[elem.id];
    for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        if (this.selectors[i] && this.selectors[i] == sel) {
            if (sel.locked == false) {
                // TODO(codedread): Ensure this exists in this module.
                console.log('WARNING! selector was released but was already unlocked');
            }
            delete this.selectorMap[elem.id];
            sel.locked = false;
            sel.selectedElement = null;
            sel.showGrips(false);

            // remove from DOM and store reference in JS but only if it exists in the DOM
            try {
                sel.selectorGroup.setAttribute('display', 'none');
            } catch(e) { }

            break;
        }
    }
};

// Function: svgedit.select.SelectorManager.getRubberBandBox
// Returns the rubberBandBox DOM element. This is the rectangle drawn by the user for selecting/zooming
svgedit.select.SelectorManager.prototype.getRubberBandBox = function() {
    if (!this.rubberBandBox) {
        this.rubberBandBox = this.selectorParentGroup.appendChild(
            svgFactory_.createSVGElement({
                'element': 'path',
                'attr': {
                    'id': 'selectorRubberBand',
                    'fill': '#22C',
                    'fill-opacity': 0.15,
                    'stroke': '#22C',
                    'stroke-width': 10.5,
                    'display': 'block',
                    'style': 'pointer-events:none'
                }
            })
        );
    }
    return this.rubberBandBox;
};


/**
 * Interface: svgedit.select.SVGFactory
 * An object that creates SVG elements for the canvas.
 *
 * interface svgedit.select.SVGFactory {
 *   SVGElement createSVGElement(jsonMap);
 *   SVGSVGElement svgRoot();
 *   SVGSVGElement svgContent();
 *
 *   Number currentZoom();
 *   Object getStrokedBBox(Element[]); // TODO(codedread): Remove when getStrokedBBox() has been put into svgutils.js
 * }
 */

/**
 * Function: svgedit.select.init()
 * Initializes this module.
 *
 * Parameters:
 * config - an object containing configurable parameters (imgPath)
 * svgFactory - an object implementing the SVGFactory interface (see above).
 */
svgedit.select.init = function(config, svgFactory) {
    config_ = config;
    svgFactory_ = svgFactory;
    selectorManager_ = new svgedit.select.SelectorManager();
};

/**
 * Function: svgedit.select.getSelectorManager
 *
 * Returns:
 * The SelectorManager instance.
 */
svgedit.select.getSelectorManager = function() {
    return selectorManager_;
};

}());
```

Dynamic create `<g>` tags based

```
<g id="selectorParentGroup" >
<rect id="selectorRubberBand" fill="#22C" fill-opacity="0.15" stroke="#22C" stroke-width="10.5" display="none" style="pointer-events:none" x="2034" y="909.800048828125" width="0" height="0"/>
<path id="selectedBox0" fill="none" stroke="#22C" stroke-dasharray="5,5" style="pointer-events:none" d="M2057,948.716552734375 L2280.5,948.716552734375 2280.5,1092 2057,1092z"/>
</g>
```

Just check both attached images, we are on the first stage (image) we to make it us the second stage - Selection area should be in over boundary as in secondary image (should be as image right side). Kindly assist me.

All suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: svg-edit has a mailing list. Why not ask this question and any other svg-edit questions there? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/svg-edit

Comment: @RobertLongson..I already asked that svg edit google group.Here SO is a common forum.Let it be asked this question in this forum also.Any more restriction to ask question based on svg? any way, Here i need to know how to change selection tool in select.js? any idea about this issues.?please help me

Comment: There's no restriction per se, just a suggestion since that's where the svg-edit experts will hang out.